# How make Raspbian boot faster from USB-stick (without SD-card) on a Raspberry pi 3 B+?

Tags: raspbian, usb, boot, pi-3b+

I already did things like disabling WiFi, Bluetooth, etc. but my gut tells me, there should be some USB-specific settings, which can make the pi boot faster. I am interested in these settings.

My current bootup time is around 50 s, reducing it by 10 s at least is my goal.
More details:

- OS is Raspbian buster lite (same install as I would have put it on an SD-card) Edit: without a GUI.
- running on a USB 2.0 USB-stick.

Edit: I consider end of booting as the point where the autologin finished.

What I had in mind is for example set the boot order in a way that the pi does not check the SD-card slot or check only 1 specific USB-hub instead of all 4.

If you need more detail ask and I will try to provide them.

Comment: How fast is fast? 1second? 10seconds? 100seconds? What OS are you running? Where is the /boot folder? Where is the rootfs? Are you using a multi-boot manager like NOOBS? Is your USB device a hard drive (HDD) or a solid state drive (SSD)?

Comment: @Dougie can you please reopen my question?

Comment: You should confirm that since you are using buster lite there is no GUI, because in that case 50s is a long time; it would make more sense if you were waiting for the desktop.

Answer (score 1):

You have not clarified what you consider the end point of booting to be. If it is when a console login prompt appears, 50 seconds is quite high for a headless setup (which is what "buster lite" implies). If you are running a GUI, it might be more on par.

If not, something is wrong (or else USB boots are actually slower).  You can `systemd-analyze` to drill down on this, for example:

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/59984/5538

You will find many discussions and examples of use here and online generally.  In that example -- I'll repaste the graph here:

[image]

Zoom in bottom right, and `getty-target` reflects the point where a login prompt should be available, about 28s -- and in the post I say it's from a "B+", meaning, a single core model.

Top left, at ~2.5s, you see systemd starting, which is about when the root filesystem comes into play; you can compare this to your USB based setup.

Another answer here about booting by me, which may or may not be of interest:

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/104183/5538